# How to extract text if HTML tags are under ::Before using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract Publication date and time from : http://www.statssa.gov.za/?page_id=1854&PPN=P6141.2&SCH=7549

unfortunetly i was not getting any output.

I tried,

```
html = urllib3.PoolManager()
Res = html.request("GET", URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(Res.data, 'html.parser')
Div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'row'})
date = Div.find('h5')
print(date.text())
```

it was throwing error as date is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rolf82 said, the div you got is not right. Try this method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req

html = req.get('http://www.statssa.gov.za/?page_id=1854&PPN=P6141.2&SCH=7549')
doc  = SimplifiedDoc(html)
div = doc.getElement('div',value='row',start='Header block@end')
h5 = div.h5
print (h5.text)
```

Result:

```
Publication date & time: 13 February 2020 @ 10:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be more specific to target the `div`. There are multiple elements with class `row` in the document, and the first does not match your expectation of containing a `h5`, that's why it fails.